24.04.1 LTS Upgrade broke NoMachine, built-in RDP and x11vnc server also fail. Is there no way to access the standard GNOME desktop remotely?
I have an Ubuntu host I use mostly as a seedbox and file server. It is connected to a physical display or display emulator at all times, but not a keyboard or mouse. I access it from Windows 10 boxen across my own private home LAN - quite flat, all one subnet.
Or I did, until I updated to 24.04.1 LTS about two weeks ago.
My preferred method has been NoMachine for years. When it failed after the update, I started a thread at the NoMachine forums. With no replies for almost two weeks at this point, I've given up hope for a solution there anytime soon. The current state maintains a connection and passes mouse and keyboard to Ubuntu from Windows, but no sound or video come back to the viewer on Windows. For the curious, my forum thread is here"
https://forum.nomachine.com/topic/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-24-04-1-lts-players-immediately-disconnects
Before NoMachine I used VNC quite a bit, so I installed X11VNC Server. It does not start, suggesting that maybe another VNC Server is running on port 5900. If one is, ss can't find it.
I am not running ufw or any soft firewall on the Ubuntu host.
A little more searching and I found that Ubuntu now offers a built-in RDP server. I activated it, and windows will connect with the built in RDP client - but no matter what session type I choose from the drop-down (incidentally, how do I determine which I should choose?), I get a black screen on windows and a fleeting message on the Ubuntu physical display : "IBus Notification Ibus should be called from the desktop session in Wayland. For KDE,...", then the RDP client disconnects. I am not running KDE. I know that GNOME is using Wayland now, but surely Canonical does too and would configure the built-in service to accommodate, right?
Any ideas, for fixes or more alternatives, welcome.
Update:
Prior to getting comments from user68186, all testing was done logged in locally and using Remote Sharing. I have since tried disabling Remote Sharing and switching to Remote Login, but the GUI switch enabling Remote Login reverts to off within 15 seconds of my setting it to on.

See this answer and that answer for more.

I've been testing while locally logged in, using remote sharing.

I have never tried nomachine. I had x11vnc working in Ubuntu 22.04, but it stopped working in 24.04. I currently use xrdp (for when I am not locally logged in) and Gnome Remote Sharing (for when I forget to logout locally). xrdp is quite stable, but sometimes I get the black screen with remote sharing. Trying again works sometimes. I have not done much testing though.
